# How old is Legendre's conjecture?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, math-history

When did Legendre stipulate his conjecture that there is a prime between $n^2$ and $(n+1)^2?$

Comment: I suspect this is in "Essai de la theorie des nombres" but can't find a citation, and this is a very long book.

Comment: Have you at least narrowed it down to within his lifetime? Legendre was born in 1752 and died in 1833, according to Britannica.

Comment: 80 years 115 days on wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

Initially conjectured in 1798 and then again in 1808.

https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath032.htm